# Singly Linked List implementation in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Here's my implementation of a Singly Linked List. Would appreciate a review.

```
public class SList<T> {

    private Node head;
    private int size;

    private class Node<T>{
       public  Node(){
            item = null;
            next = null;
        }
        public  Node(T item){
            this.item = item;
            this.next = null;
        }
        private T item;
        private Node next;
    }//end of node

    //constructor
    public SList(){
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    public void add(T item){
        Node p = new Node(item);
        if(head == null){
            head = p;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        p.next = head;
        head = p;
        size++;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return size == 0;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }
    public void remove(T item){
        Node current = head;
        while(current.next != item){

            if(current.next == null) {
                System.out.println("Item doesn't exist in the list:");
                return;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = current.next.next;
        size--;
    }

    public void insertAfter(T item1, T item2){
        Node current = head;
        Node p = new Node(item2);
        do{
            if(current == null) {
                System.out.println("Item doesn't exist in the list:");
                return;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }while(current.item != item1);
        Node q = current.next;
        current.next = p;
        p.next = q;
        size++;

    }

    public void insertBefore(T item1, T item2){
        Node current = head;
        Node p = new Node(item2);
        do{
            if(current.next == null) {
                System.out.println("Item doesn't exist in the list:");
                return;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }while(current.next.item != item1);
        Node q = current.next;
        current.next = p;
        p.next = q;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.next = null;` all those null initializes are redundant as Java uses default values for fields. The default value for `Object`s is `null.`

Answer (score 6):

### General

**Default Values**

Java uses default values for all its fields. Meaning :

> ```
> public  Node(){
>     item = null;
>     next = null;
> }
> ```

Does nothing except take up space for you. I would remove it, and the other lines / constructors like it. Some consider it bad practice to rely on the default values, you can then explicitly state the default value of a field on the same row as you are declaring it.

```
private Node head = null;
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

**Inconsistency**

You are inconsistent at spacing your code. I also recommend having fields at the right below the class declaration. I should not have to look for the fields, I want to find them instantly.

**Bug in remove, insertBefore**

If head is `null`, then `current.next` will throw a `NullPointerException`. I suggest guarding against `null` for `head` first in the method.

```
if (head == null) {
    System.out.println ("Item doesn't exist in the list.");
    return;
}
```

### Nitpicks

**`public void add(T item)`**

You always execute the `size++;` why have it in two different places? And not directly under `Node p = new Node (item);`

**`public boolean isEmpty()`**

Looks perfect, why can't every method turn out to be like this? One option is to match against `head == null` as well, however in terms micro-optimization, it is slower.

**`public int getSize()`**

Nothing needs to be said, a simple getter.

**`public void remove(T item)`**

Instead of letting it handle the error printing, let `remove` return a `boolean`, `true` if removed, `false` if not, making it more flexible to use in future applications.

Answer (score 4):

`remove` needs to check for an empty list (`head == null`) before searching.  And I think you meant `while (current.item != item)` in there.

`insertAfter` advances past the first element before checking for the value, so it will fail if you're trying to insert after the first one.  `insertBefore` has the same problem.

The 'find node in list' code can go into a method, rather than duplicating it in several methods.

Comment: Is current.next.item, you have to stop one node before to be able to skip it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the remove function

```
while(current.next != item){
```

You are comparing a node with an item, you should compare `current.next.item`.

I would also add and use getters/setters methods to Node class: `getNext()`, `getItem()`, `setNext()`, `setItem()`.